# Why does HttpRequest have GetFormAsync method?

Tags: asp.net-core

`GetFormAsync` makes the assumption that the request body is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is often not the case. HTTPAbstractions should enable all payload media types to be handled in a consistent way.